# Why os.path.join returns result with 2 slashes?

Tags: python, os.path, path-separator

Why does it add 2 '\' instead of 1 '/'?
I am trying to create a cats folder(using Jupyter Notebook) inside the train directory for my model where I will place the cat's images. As it os.path.join returns 2 '\' that is why I am unable to copy/place images there through code. Can anybody help me better understand os.path.join as I have gone through several articles but those were of no help

```
base_dir = "CNN_Working/cats_and_dogs_small"
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)

train_cats_dir
```

This is what it returns

```
'CNN_Working\\cats_and_dogs_small\\train\\cats'
```

instead of one '/' it returns 2 '\'?

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped in Python.

Comment: On Windows, the standard directory separator is backslash.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Barmar but why does it add extra backslash?

Comment: Python presents the string in the same form as would be needed in Python source code. Your path contains `\train`. In a Python string `"\t"` means a tab character. So if you mean backslash followed by `t` you have to type it as `"\\t"`. This is called "escaping" because you want to escape from the convention that the backslash indicates something special.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're working on a Windows system.

Running your code on MacOS I get:

```
(base) X 68884371 % python3 script.py
CNN_Working/cats_and_dogs_small/train
CNN_Working/cats_and_dogs_small/train/cats
```

When you're running on Windows, the directory seprator is `\`, not `/`.
But, because of Python's escaping, when you print it, you see `\\`, because Python escapes the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using Windows and while using Python on It you commonly use double backslashes '\'. On unix systems you'll got the '/'.